Is this duplicate question a valid candidate for deletion?
My question here: How to remove elements from list while iterating through it without skipping future iterations was marked as a duplicate.
Reading through:

Should I delete duplicate questions? and
Should I delete my question if it is marked as a duplicate?

I believe my question falls more into the category:

Your search skills were lacking when you asked and future visitors will find the duplicate also without your question

...as described in 1, rather than being a useful "signpost" as described in 2.
Is this a valid case for deletion to reduce noise on this site?

The duplicate target has multiple questions marked as duplicate so I'd agree it's not a useful signpost. But given it has upvotes you can't delete it unilaterally and we'd need 3 trusted users to vote to delete it.

Considering that your question, and an answer, have a positive score, why do you feel that deletion is worthwhile when several users have found it valuable? Generally deleted "good" content isn't something we want done.

Am I wrong to think this was more a question for code review? There is working but far from optimal code, asking for a more elegant solution. Sounds a little off-topic for Stack Overflow to me. The question in the title and the question in the body just don't match up very well. The question in the title is a fair Stack Overflow question, definitely a duplicate.

@Gimby as the OP (a long time ago), I agree - I was a novice, the code isn't optimal, and shouldn't be emulated by others seeking a solution to the question's title. While I wasn't looking for code review, I lacked the language/understanding to find the answer I was looking for.

@ThomA please see Gimby's comment and my response: this is why I feel deletion is worthwhile (also noting Abdul's answer highlighting several other duplicates - this post adds noise with little "signposting" benefit).

@Moley an old unwritten site rule that has gotten lost in the mail along the way and probably needs a little bit of a reboot is "Don't delete value". The question is there, it's closed, it received upvotes and several decent looking answers. It's beyond the point of curation now, time to move on.
